# javascript sleep function by Promise in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, sleep

I intend to open a series of urls in firefox,each one should be opened after another in 10 minutes, here is my code should be execute in firebug console:

```
function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
var urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.bing.com/","https://www.reddit.com/"];
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
    sleep(600000 * i).then(() => {
    window.open(urls[i]); 
})
```

But it didn't work, could anyone help me ? Thank you~

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/5647260

Answer (score 7):

`Sleep` function is executing **asynchronously** and the `for` loop finished before executing any of the `sleep` calls.

So, the last value of `for` loop will be `3`, and `window.open` function will receive as parameter the `value` of `urls[3]` which is undefined.

Have a look:

```js
function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
var urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.bing.com/","https://www.reddit.com/"];
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
    sleep(600*i).then(() => {
    console.log(i); 
})
```

**One solution is to use `let` keyword.**

You should use `let` keyword in order to use **enclosed** value of `i` variable.

```
function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
var urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.bing.com/","https://www.reddit.com/"];
for(let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
    sleep(6000*i).then(() => {
    window.open(urls[i]); 
})
```

[jsFiddle solution.](https://jsfiddle.net/wp4tctp2/)

Comment: Thanks Alex, it works. I found javascript is more difficult. Thanks bro~

Comment: @Wang, you're welcome. Don't forget to accepts answer in order to help other people.

Answer (score 6):

Promises work very well with async/await functions.

The following will declare a new asynchronous function (i.e. it will execute outside after the function is called). The code of the async function reads very easily because it reads like a synchronous function:

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay))
}

(async function() {
    const urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.bing.com/","https://www.reddit.com/"]
    for (let url of urls) {
        await sleep(1000)
        console.log(url)
    }
})()
```

Here's a version using Promise chaining:

```js
function sleep(delay) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay))
}

const urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.bing.com/","https://www.reddit.com/"];
let p = Promise.resolve();
for (let url of urls) {
    p = p.then( function () {
        return sleep(1000);
    } );
    p = p.then( function () {
        console.log(url);
        return Promise.resolve();
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is i will =3 on in all 3 cases, so you need to save i for example

```
function sleep (time, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(i), time));
}
var urls = ["https://www.google.com/","https://www.bing.com/","https://www.reddit.com/"];
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
    sleep(1 * i, i).then((index) => {
    console.log(urls[index]); 
})
```

But even this will not help, because first new tab will opened, your code in inactive tab will be stopped by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Think a interval + [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) would be better suited for this, here is an example with es6

```js
const urls = [
  'https://www.google.com/',
  'https://www.bing.com/',
  'https://www.reddit.com'
]

const entries = urls.entries()

const loop = setInterval(() => {
  const {value, done} = entries.next()
  done ? clearInterval(loop) : open(value)
}, 600 * 10)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)() or [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_win_setTimeout.asp)() instead of sleep to achieve this.