# Is this a correct understanding of async/await?

Tags: javascript

```js
function injectText(value, selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = value
      resolve()
    }, 500)
  })
}

async function printWord(word, selector) {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    await injectText(word.substring(0, i + 1), selector)
  }
}

async function run() {
  await printWord('Hello', '.hello')
  await printWord('there!', '.there')
}

run()
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="there"></div>
```

I've used Promise and async/await to print `Hello there!`  letter after letter with the delay of 500ms. It works as intended, however, I'm not sure if I understand what happens when function `run()` executes.

1. `await` before `printWord` means that execution of `async` funtion `run` is paused until Promise is resolved or rejected.
2. Function `printWord` is an async function. I'm not returning anything from it, therefore `undefined` is returned at the end of function run. Async functions always return Promises, therefore, it automatically returns Promise which automatically resolves with `undefined` value? Is this what happens?
3. Then it jumps to second `await printWord` where the same logic applies.

Am I understanding it correctly? I appreciate your help.

Comment: If it runs like you expect, then yes, you understand async/await

Comment: @JaromandaX It runs but I feel like a monkey pressing buttons.

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, I needed to make sure I understand It correctly.

Comment: You can always `console.log(await whatever())` to see the resolved value. It'll be undefined here as you suspect. If you used `resolve("foo")` it'd log `"foo"`. I'd use a [generic pause/sleep function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628787/6243352), though, instead of `injectText` which is a sort of peculiar abstraction.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! I didn't even think of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the `run()` function's execution is paused whenever there is an `await` for it to handle. The function will pause its execution twice before resolving itself.
2. Yes, an async function does return a Promise; however, realize that promises *resolve*, and they don't *return*. At least, in javascript (since async/await is just sugar for Promises) they don't really return, but they resolve.
3. Yes.